# Selenium: NoSuchElementException Thrown on the Line Where I Wait

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver

This is an odd variety of a common problem.

I am running a Selenium project using a headless firefox browser.

I get the common NoSuchElementExceptions. That's nothing new. However, attempting to resolve them through explicit waits does not resolve the issue.

For example, the following line throws the NoSuchElementException:

```
WebElement trackingInbox = methodDriver.findElement(By.id("inbox-widget-container-id"));
```

I then add the following above this line:

```
FluentWait wait = new FluentWait(methodDriver);
wait.withTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
wait.pollingEvery(250, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("inbox-widget-container-id")));

WebElement trackingInbox = methodDriver.findElement(By.id("inbox-widget-container-id"));
```

In the first instance, I get the exception at the "methodDriver.findElement . . . ."

In the second instance I get it at the "wait.until . . . "

This happens when I wait for "presenceOf . . ." and when I wait for "visibilityOf . . ." The way it appears, the element has to be available *before* I wait for it, which appears to defeat the purpose.

The way it currently appears, I have no option but to add implicit waits, but I know there must be *some* way to do the explicit waits such that the element does not have to be available *before* I wait for it.

I wonder if there are any ideas as to what I am doing wrong and if there are any principles I can go by to determine whether a particular wait would be useful or not.

Comment: Does it work when not running headless?

Comment: No. At least not for the particular line I listed above (I get this issue in multiple places). Running with headed firefox still results in the NoSuchElementException being thrown when I run "wait.until . . . "

Comment: And using explicit wait (WebDriverWait) doesn't work either?

Comment: Ahh, that actually seems to work. I tried it both headed and heedlessly. But how would that work but the FluentWait not work? What is it about these waits that causes one to need the element *prior* to waiting?

Comment: http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/implicit -explicit-n-fluent-wait/ has a good explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have actually forgot to call `ignoring` function at the end, This ignoring is what you want. When you are waiting for visibility of the element, it might occur that element doesn't exist but If you use Ignoring function, it would ignore if such error happens until it meet with the given condition.

```
   Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
       .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
       .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
       .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
```

Comment: Thanks, RAJ. I will check this solution out when I get a chance and report back. Switching from FluentWait to WebDriverWait, as smit9234 suggested, ended up doing the job, but I'll complete the record sometime soon. I am guessing that the WebDriverWait might ignore the NoSuchElementException implicitly?

Comment: @somexp12  yeah, it would eliminate implicitly, the main reason `ignoring` exist because of this reason, when you check for visibility of object, it would call the find_element first to get element first because element has to exist before it checks the visibility of that element, but If element doesn't exist, it causes the error, so to avoid that, `ignoring` function is used in Fluent wait. By the way If my code works, don't forget to accept my answer!

Comment: Ah, well it looks like both options work. So, two solutions to this. 1. Remember to ignore the exception you are trying to resolve and 2. Go for the WebdriverWait. It also is important to recognize that someone might wait for the visibility of an element whilst the *presence* of that element is assumed, in which case the element not being present (NoSuchElementException) would represent a genuine exception. So, I have to indicate if this not the case.

Comment: Hmm, sorry. Did not know what it meant to "accept" an answer. Probably interpreted that to involve upvoting. Got that remedied, as it should have been from the start.